# live search with angularJS with categories and tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search

First of all I want to say I am following this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Zkm/4/) for Advanced live-search with AngularJS, which is working great, but for my scenario I need to search for both catergories and category childs.

Example list:

```
$scope.names = [
         {
         name: "Kitchen",
         tags: [
         "Knife",
         "Plate",
         "Fork"
         ]
         },
         {
         name: "Garage",
         tags: [
         "Car",
         "Wrench",
         ]
         }
```

Scenario Search:

Input Search:

```
knife
```

Result:

```
<li><b>Kitchen</b></li>
<li>Knife</li>
```

Scenario Search 2:

Input Search:

```
garage
```

Result:

```
<li><b>Garage</b></li>
```

I've tried to make some form of 'double' `ng-repeat` with something

like this: `ng-repeat="name in names || name in names` by separating categories from childs but then there will be problem with populating the list. I also don't know the correct operator for `AND` but I can imagine there is a lot better solution for this but I can't figure out how, Note that I am pretty new to AngularJS and JS.

Comment: You might consider pre-processing the array into a flat one dimensional array and then use that to perform your search.

Comment: yea that would be fine but how do I add bold text into catnames?

Comment: Each array element can have an optional category property. While you're processing the original array you can attach it to each tag.

Comment: I can't store both categories and objects because in my data-list I have same words sometimes in both as category and tags, I getting the following Error:[ngRepeat:dupes].

Comment: What would you output if I searched for knife and it showed up in two categories?

Comment: At first, `[ngRepeat:dupes]` error, can be easily solved just using `track by $index` in your `ngRepeat`.. by the way, what's the expected result if you search for *"Garage"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make *filter* works in both arrays, you have to create a *custom* `filter`.

See it *working*:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
  .filter('customFilter', customFilter);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MainCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.names = [
    {
      name: "Kitchen",
      tags: [
        "Knife",
        "Plate",
        "Fork"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      name: "Garage",
      tags: [
        "Car",
        "Wrench",
      ]
    }
  ];
}

function customFilter() {
  return function(items, search) {
    if (!search) return items;
    
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(function(item) {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1 || item.tags.filter(function(tag) {
        return tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1;
      }).length;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="search">
  <ul ng-repeat="obj in names | customFilter: search track by $index">
    <li><strong ng-bind="obj.name"></strong></li>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in obj.tags | filter: search track by $index" ng-bind="tag"></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.